Where to find detailed Lake Formation logs when getting "insufficient lake formation permissions" error?
I am trying to debug why a user in the RedshiftQueryLogV2 cannot query a particular external table. We are controlling user permissions via Lake Formation.
I have granted the permissions that are needed for Lake Formation to allow this user to query this data however I am still getting the AwsClientException: AccessDeniedException from glue - Insufficient Lake Formation permission(s) on ... error message.
I have tried to query sys_query_history table and all of those system tables within redshift which normally show queries and if they failed however I am surprised to find that when LF denies your permission to query something that the Redshift system tables receive no record of this.
I'd like to know if there is some other place I can go to find more details on this particular error. I have tried searching within cloudwatch and cloudtrail but I may have not known where exactly to look.
